# Is there a categorical version of the splitting principle?

Tags: ct.category-theory, kk-theory

One of many places we see a "splitting principle" at work is in the category $\mathsf{Vect}(X)$ of complex vector bundles over a compact connected Hausdorff space $X$.   For any object $E$ in this category, we can find a bundle of compact Hausdorff spaces $p: F \to X$ such that

$$ p^* : \mathsf{Vect}(X) \to \mathsf{Vect}(F) $$

maps $E$ to a vector bundle $p^*(E)$ that splits as a direct sum of line bundles.

Given that this same idea shows up in many other contexts, I'm hoping there's a general version that subsumes a lot of examples.  Maybe something like the following.

Just for brevity, let's say a **2-rig** is a symmetric monoidal $k$-linear category with absolute colimits.  (Such 2-rigs were studied in [a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.00190) I wrote with Joe Moeller and Todd Trimble, but there we were assuming the field $k$ had characteristic zero, and here I'd rather not—unless it turns out to be helpful.)  Having absolute colimits is the same as having biproducts and having splittings of all idempotents.  A **map of 2-rigs** is a symmetric monoidal $k$-linear functor; such functors automatically preserve absolute colimits.

I'm using 2-rigs to generalize categories of vector bundles: $\mathsf{Vect}(X)$ is an example of a 2-rig when $k = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and the above map $p^\ast : \mathsf{Vect}(X) \to \mathsf{Vect}(F)$ is a map of 2-rigs.   (Note that $\mathsf{Vect}(X)$ is not an abelian category.)

Given an object $E$ in a 2-rig $\mathsf{R}$, I would like to find a map of 2-rigs

$$ f: \mathsf{R} \to \mathsf{R}' $$

such that $f^*$ is a direct sum of **line objects**, meaning objects $L$ with duals $L^*$ such that $L \otimes L^* \cong I$, $I$ being the unit object.

**Are any general theorems along these lines already known?**

Of course such theorems become less interesting if $f$ is "far from one-to-one".   It may be too much to demand that $f$ is fully faithful, though I'd like to if I could.  But we can define the Grothendieck ring $K(\mathsf{R})$ for any 2-rig $\mathsf{R}$, and in the vector bundle example

$$ K(p^\ast) : K(\mathsf{Vect}(X)) \to K(\mathsf{Vect}(F)) $$

is monic.   So, in the general case, a fallback position would be to ask for a map $f: \mathsf{R} \to \mathsf{R}'$ such that $K(f)$ is monic.  **Are there general conditions under which we can achieve this?**

I expect we'll need some finiteness condition to get $f(E)$ to split as a finite direct sum of line objects.  Furthermore, as pointed out by Simon Henry below, the splitting principle for $\mathrm{Vect}(X)$ as stated above fails when $X$ is not connected: this is a clue as to the further conditions we will need.  For example, it may help to assume that $\mathrm{End}(I)$ has no idempotents other than $0$ and $1$.   This is true for $\mathrm{Vect}(X)$ when $X$ is connected, but not otherwise.  For each connected component $C \subseteq X$, multiplication by the characteristic function of that component gives an idempotent in $\mathrm{End}(I)$, and splitting this idempotent we obtain a vector bundle $E$ that restricts to a trivial line bundle on $C$ and a 0-dimensional vector bundle on $X-C$.  Thus, when $X$ has more than one component, $E$ is not a direct sum of line bundles.

Comment: Isn't there trivial solution if we don't put any additional assumption on $f$ (such as being conservative or faithful) ? For example can't we just take $R'$ to be the terminal $2$-Rig in which every object become a line bundle. Or take $R'$ to be the universal $2$-Rig under $R$ in which $E$ decompose as a sum of $n$ line bundle ?

Comment: What if you regard the 2-rig as a 2-category (or rather bicategory) with only one object and then you invert all 1-morphisms? You would need to do it in an enriched setting to keep k-linearity in 2-morphisms. Completing w.r.t. coproducts and idempotents is something you can always do in an essentially unique way. If you insist in symmetry then you probably have to go higher in the categorical direction. This has the disadvantage that every object becomes a line bundle, though.

Comment: In algebraic geometry, the splitting principle is typically weaker, giving (after pullback) a filtration of $E$ whose graded pieces are line bundles, rather than an actual splitting. Are you interested in such weaker decompositions too? If not, then I imagine that some substantive, rather restrictive conditions will be needed to get actual splittings.

Comment: Probably in the same line as Tim Campion remark: It also seems to me that your motivating example of Vect(X) only works if X is connected (otherwise, the "number" of line bundle needed will depends on the connected component, and it won't work as stated). That suggest that maybe, the type of decomposition you are looking for isn't quite the right thing in a more general setting...

Comment: I believe that other, weaker senses in which a category can be generated by line bundles / invertible objects have been studied by people interested in K-theory. I'm not sure of the terminology, but being generated by vector bundles / dualizable objects goes by the name of "the resolution property". It brings to mind also Barthel, Schlank, and Stapleton's use of [Pic-generated categories](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-019-00943-9), though I don't know if there are results saying that you can "resolve" a non-Pic-generated category by Pic-generated ones.

Comment: @SimonHenry wrote: "Isn't there a trivial solution if we don't put any additional assumption on f (such as being conservative or faithful)?"  Yes, that's why I said "Of course such theorems become less interesting if f is "far from one-to-one"," and suggested an additional condition.

Comment: "For example can't we just take R′ to be the terminal 2-Rig in which every object become a line bundle?"  Yes, in the terminal 2-rig we have $I = 0$: the unit for the tensor product is a zero object.  Here every object is a line object according to the definition I gave.

Comment: @TimCampion wrote: " Are you interested in such weaker decompositions too?"   Sure, I'll take anything I can get.

Comment: Here's one obstruction to think about. If $L$ is a line object, then $\chi(L)$ (the endomorphism of the unit object given by a figure 8 string diagram constructed with $L$ and $L^\ast$) has the property that $\chi(L)^2 = 1 \in End(I)$. Since the Euler characteristic / trace $\chi$ is preserved by symmetric monoidal functors and is additive in direct sums (maybe also in exact sequences?), it follows that if $R$ has dualizable objects with "exotic" Euler characteristics (e.g. non-integers), then $End_{R'}(I)$ is going to need to have a rich supply of square roots of 1 to add up to them.

Comment: Corrected version of an earlier comment of mine.  "Or take R′ to be the universal 2-rig under R in which E decompose as a sum of n line objects". This is more interesting, but such a 2-rig under R may need to be the terminal 2-rig. For example if R = Vect and E is a vector space of dimension 3, I believe there is no 2-rig under R such that E maps to a direct sum of 2 line objects, except for the terminal 2-rig. So finding conditions under which your universal 2-rig exists and is non-terminal may already be interesting.

Comment: @TimCampion - I know lots of *braided* monoidal $k$-linear categories with dualizable objects $E$ having non-integral $\chi(E)$, but not symmetric monoidal ones.   Do you know examples?

Comment: @JohnBaez I do not know any examples! I would love to know if there's a good reason for this.

Comment: @SimonHenry wrote: "It also seems to me that your motivating example of Vect(X) only works if X is connected (otherwise, the "number" of line bundle needed will depends on the connected component, and it won't work as stated)."  I guess you're one of those people who allows bundles to have nonisomorphic fibers on different components.  I'm not.  But your version of Vect(X) is still a 2-rig, so your main point is correct: we need conditions on our 2-rig to get a nontrivial splitting principle to hold, and your counterexample is something those conditions must rule out!

Comment: @TimCampion - the Doplicher-Roberts reconstruction theorem gives conditions on a 2-rig under which objects have integral dimensions: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Doplicher-Roberts+reconstruction+theorem

Comment: @JohnBaez If you want Vect(X) to have idempotent spliting, you can't ask all fibers to be isomorphic !

Comment: @SimonHenry - good point!   In my question I will restrict X to be connected, to make it true that every vector bundle splits as a sum of line bundles.   But the fact that this fails when X is not connected is a very useful clue as to the conditions we may need on a 2-rig, or an object in it, for a splitting principle to hold.

Comment: In my revised question I suggested the condition that End(I) contain no nontrivial idempotents.  This is a weakening of one condition in the Doplicher-Roberts reconstruction theorem: that End(I) be 1-dimensional.  This condition (combined with others) lets them prove certain 2-rigs consist of unitary reps of compact groups or supergroups.     Dropping it, we get categories of unitary reps of compact groupoids, or supergroupoids.

Comment: Maybe it could be useful to think about the decategorified version of the problem, ie the corresponding question about $\lambda$-rings. Now there are several purely algebraic variants of the splitting principle in the theory of $\lambda$-rings, but they don't match yours because they use a different notion of a "line bundle element".

Comment: Instead the statement is something like: if $R$ is a $\lambda$-ring and $x \in R$ is "positive" (there exists $n$ such that $\lambda^k(x)=0$ for $k>n$) then there exists an injection $R \hookrightarrow R'$ into a larger $\lambda$-ring, in which $x$ is a sum of $n$ line elements (elements $x_i$ such that $\lambda^k(x_i)=0$ for $k>1$). But an analogue of your question is: if $x \in R$ is arbitrary, does there exist an injection $R \hookrightarrow R'$ into a larger $\lambda$-ring, in which $x$ is a sum of units?

Comment: I'm happy to switch my definition, say a line object $x$ of a 2-rig $\mathsf{R}$ is one with $\Lambda^k(x) = 0$ for $k  > 1$, and try to show that under some conditions for any object $x$ with $\Lambda^k(x) = 0$ for all $k > n$ for some $n$ there's a fully faithful functor $f: \mathsf{R} \hookrightarrow \mathsf{R'}$ such that $f(x)$ is a sum of line objects.   Where can I see a proof of your analogous $\lambda$-ring statement, @DanPetersen?

Comment: @JohnBaez One reference is §6 of Atiyah-Tall.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there can be a reasonable such splitting principle, even in the weakest sense you asked about (i.e. $K_0(\mathsf R) \to K_0(\mathsf R')$ is injective) and in the case when the ground ring $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.

Let us make the standing assumption that $\mathrm{End}(\mathbf 1)$ has no nontrivial idempotent, as suggested in the question. Then if $L$ is a line object, we must have either $\wedge^n(L)=0$ for all $n>1$, or $\mathrm{Sym}^n(L)=0$ for all $n>1$. Indeed consider
$$ L^{\otimes 2} \cong \wedge^2(L) \oplus \mathrm{Sym}^2(L). $$
If both summands here are nontrivial then we get nontrivial orthogonal idempotents in $\mathrm{End}(L)\cong \mathrm{End}(\mathbf 1)$. The argument generalizes to higher $n$.

From this it follows that any finite sum of line objects is annihilated by some Schur functor. More precisely the sum of $n$ even and $m$ odd line objects is killed by the Schur functor given by an $(n +1) \times ( m +1 )$ Young diagram. This follows from Pieri's formula.

So let for example $\mathsf{R}$ be the 2-rig $\mathsf{Poly}$ of polynomial functors $\mathsf{Vect}\to \mathsf{Vect}$, and let $\mathrm{id} \in \mathsf R$ be the identity functor. If $f:\mathsf{R} \to \mathsf R'$ is such that $f(\mathrm{id})$ is a sum of line bundles then $K_0(\mathsf R) \to K_0(\mathsf R')$ can not be injective, since all Schur functors applied to $\mathrm{id}$ are nonzero in $K_0(\mathsf R) \cong \Lambda$.

Comment: So just to clarify, the 2-Rig "Poly" is a concrete example of one which does not admit a splitting principle in the sense of the OP's question (where $K_0(R) \to K_0(R')$ is injective)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And it suggests a natural weaker statement which might be true under some hypotheses: any object of $\mathsf R $ which is killed by some Schur functor can be split into line objects in a larger 2-rig.

Comment: One could also make the statement that the map from $K_0(R)$ to the product of $K_0(R')$ over all $R'$ that send this object to a sum of line bundles is injective.

Comment: Nice.  We might think an object of a 2-rig killed by some Schur functor is "finite-dimensional" in some generalized sense, since in $\mathsf{Vect}$ these objects are just the finite-dimensional vector spaces.  I'm happy to limit my conjecture to objects that are finite-dimensional in this sense.   Are there 2-rigs with finite-dimensional objects, in this sense, that are not killed by $\Lambda^n$ or $S^n$ for any $n$?

Comment: Sure. The super vector space $\mathbb Q^{1|1}$ is annihilated by a Schur functor $S^\lambda$ if and only if $\lambda$ contains a $2 \times 2$ box.

Comment: By the way, although an infinite-dimensional vector space in $\mathsf {Vect}$ is not annihilated by any Schur functor, this does not give a counterexample to your original question in its weakest form, i.e. when you ask for an object to be split into line bundles along a functor such that $K_0(\mathsf R) \to K_0(\mathsf R')$ is injective: $K_0(\mathsf{Vect})=0$, by the Eilenberg swindle! So the identity polynomial functor is not finite-dimensional, but it's finite enough to be nontrivial in $K$-theory, so to speak.